# Improve the runtime of hashtable operations by keeping lists in sorted order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, hashtable

The following is a question from the textbook *Introduction to Algorithms*, however a solution to the problem is not given...

> Professor Marley hypothesizes that he can obtain substantial performance gains by modifying the chaining scheme to keep each list in sorted order. How does the professor’s modification affect the running time for successful searches, unsuccessful searches, insertions, and deletions?

For this question I believe the running time would be the same for searching if the list are sorted, because they are linked lists, and one still needs to traverse the entire list in order to find a value.

For inserting however, it would take longer because one can't just insert a value to the head of the list because the order must now be preserved. It would no longer be *O(1)* I believe.

For deletion I have no idea.

In fact, I'm not quite sure if any of my answers are correct, can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is related to linked list?

Comment: It seems that Professor Marley's idea is not going to revolution the computer science world :)
As you said, searching would not be faster in the worst case, and inserting would be slower. As for deleting, it is very similar to searching .... 
(yes, your answers so far are correct, given that the sorted lists do not become arrays)

Comment: @libik now that you mention it, it might not be its rather unclear whether it is or not

Comment: Something else to think about: how big are the lists used to store the elements in each bucket? What sort of savings are you likely to get even if you heavily optimized those lists?

Comment: I guess the idea behind using sorted lists is that it's possible to do a binary search on them to locate an item. Actually, an even better approach would be to use binary trees instead of sorted lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the performance by sorting elements in the same slot, but not with a linked list.
Instead, probably using a balanced tree *(and, more often than not, it's `red-black tree`)*.

But, there is a trade-off, only when the elements in the same slot exceed certain amount, it would actually improve the performance.

---

### Example - `Java`'s `HashMap`

In Java 8, `HashMap` is rewritten to use both `linked list` and `red-black tree` to represent elements in a slot.

There are `treeify()` and `untreeify()` operations to convert between the 2 structures, triggered by pre-defined thresholds.